# Can Spark directory lookup for partition filtering be parallel?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet

I have a large number of directories and use Spark partition filtering to read a DataFrame. I find that I look up the partition directories directly on the file system, I can do this at least an *order of magnitude* faster than Spark can. Am I missing something? Why isn't Spark looking for directories in parallel?

Let's say for example `/mydata/date=2020-09-01`, `/mydata/date=2020-09-02`, etc., and I want only `2020-09-28` to `2020-09-29`.

I can:

```
val paths = List("/mydata/date=2020-09-28", "/mydata/date=2020-09-29")
spark.read.format("parquet").option("basePath", "/mydata").load(paths: _*)
```

Or, I can:

```
val dates = List("2020-09-28", "2020-09-29")
spark.read.format("parquet").load("/mydata").filter($"date".isin(dates: _*))
```

In the first case, I will have to scan the directories myself to be sure the partition files exist, or else `load` will fail "file not found" if any one path is missing.

In the second case, Spark will scan the directories for me, and open the minimum number of files using partition filtering.

However, if the number of directories is large, and they are on slow media such as S3, I can look for the directories much, much faster than spark by using a parallel collection. Something like:

```
val goodPaths = paths.par.map(checkExist).toList
```

I would rather let Spark do what Spark is good at, but it is incredibly slow to scan S3 like this on a single thread. Am I missing some configuration option to allow Spark to make use of all of the cores of the node?

I see this on both Spark 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

Thats probably because:

```scala
spark.sql.sources.parallelPartitionDiscovery.threshold
```

is defaulting to 32?